# StackOverflow API returns only 20 questions

Tags: python, stackexchange-api

The following code returns only 20 questions/results. How can I retrieve the whole number of questions for that date?

```
base_url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3'
endpoint = '/questions'
params = {
    'site': 'stackoverflow',
    'tagged': tag,
    'fromdate': start_date,
    'todate': end_date,
    'filter': 'default'  # Use 'default' or specify your desired filter
}

response = requests.get(base_url + endpoint, params=params)
data = response.json()
```

Comment: see page and pagesize parameters [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions)

Comment: thank you - can you please elaborate? I looked at the page, but I can't figure out how to tackle the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: What *is* the problem? All APIs use paging for scalability reasons. Returning a ton of results means a lot of RAM and a lot of IO is used, while the database remains locked for a long time. All APIs use some kind of paging instead

Comment: "I looked at the page, but I can't figure out how to tackle the problem". To be clear: the problem is that when you use the API, you only get 20 results at a time, right? See how it shows you that there is a `pagesize` parameter you can use when you make the API query? What happens if you try using different values for that? Do you see how that corresponds to the number of results you get? (What do you suppose a "page" might refer to, in this context? What would it mean if the "size" of the "page" changes?)

Comment: every query to the API returns a 'has_more' boolean, so that one can increase the `page` and get the next batch of results. the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

according to [page doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging) pagesize can be any value between 0 and 100 and defaults to 30. if with the default values you only get 20 questions, it's probably because there are only this many questions fitting your tag in the time span given (can't tell as it's not included)
otherwise you would get 30 results and would need to paginate through the different pages of results with page param like so

```
base_url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3'
endpoint = '/questions'
page = 1
pagesize = 30
page_results = []
while (page == 1 or page_results["has_more"] == True) :
  params = {
    'site': 'stackoverflow',
    'page': page,
    'pagesize' : pagesize,
    'tagged': tag,
    'fromdate': start_date,
    'todate': end_date,
    'filter': 'default'  # Use 'default' or specify your desired filter
  }
  page_results = requests.get(base_url + endpoint, params=params).json()
  page +=1
```

Comment: sure thanks - but I'd like to take all the questions, not only 100 or 30. How can I do that?

Comment: @Dimitris this is what it does, the api limit your request to a maximum of 100 item response, so you need to request the X pages of Y items (Y being 100 max). basically, keep paging until the api answear an empty array

Comment: There are no such operators as `||` and `++` in Python.

Comment: @Dimitris you can't get all questions, in any API, not just StackOverflow's. Unless the API's creator knows only a few items will be returned, everyone implements some kind of paging.

Comment: ok, I didn't know that. So I will iterate on pages that return max 30 results, until I get no results? That's clunky

Comment: @Dimitris the default result number is 30, the max is 100, to set with pagesize param

Comment: No, what you tried to do would be very clunky. It would prevent you from asking this question because the server would be frozen trying to return then 1M questions per day

Comment: @Dimitris if you tried the same at work, the DBA would come screaming asking who froze the CFO's reports. If someone was calling *your* API the same way, you'd be the one screaming as your API would eat up all RAM

Comment: @Dimitris if you want all questions, why not retrieve the [StackOverflow database backup](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/)? Instead of retrieving the data little by little, you can get it all at once.

Comment: PS: Stock exchanges don't give you unthrottled access to their data either. In fact, unless you pay handsomely, they won't even give you real-time access. They'll buffer and throttle access. If you try to retrieve historical data you get paged results too.

Comment: I only want the date and the tags for a question. No need to download 460GB of data - I'll go with the API. I want to have the entire database. I just wanted to have *all* the questions for a single date, and I'll iterate from 06/15/2008 to today. How's that?

Comment: All the questions for all time, one day at a time, is still all questions, so you'll end up downloading everything. If you [check the actual data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) you'll see the actual English SO Posts file is 18GB zipped. You'll probably download that file faster than trying to retrieve the same contents through the API. Download tools can easily recover from network problems, download in parallel or retry in chunks

Comment: I get {'error_id': 502,
 'error_message': 'too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 83960 seconds',
 'error_name': 'throttle_violation'}

Comment: Should I add some delay between the API requests? Does anyone know?

Comment: Yes, that's generally what it's telling you. However, there are now two issues here: 1) Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum** - the purpose of questions here **is not** to get the code in your project to work, but to contribute to a searchable Q&A library. 2) you now have questions that are off topic; you are asking about API design and more generally "how does the Internet work in 2023?" questions, not questions about writing code.

Comment: @safir The `len(page_results) == pagesize` isn't the best approach: `page_results["has_more"]` gives you a `True` if there are more items (and `False` otherwise).